# Can't get full width HTML / CSS

Tags: html, width, fullscreen, css

My problem is that I can't get the full width and height, I have tried lots of things but I can't get it right and now I am asking you guys to help me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jokGR.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSkE7.jpg

What you are seeing here is a picture of my header.

Everything works but I can't remove the background lines at the outide of the image as you can see it: left, right and top

so how do I fix that?

Comment: What's your css/html of the page?

Comment: Looks like there is some padding/margin space somewhere creating that.  Can't really say where because all you've given us to work off of are images.  Go in and add padding: 0; and margin: 0; to the html elements in that area.  Eventually you'll find one that does it.

Another idea would be to use chrome dev tools or firefox firebug to find that padding.  Right click your header and click inspect element.

Comment: please add a jsfiddle so we can take a look at the sourcecode and also the css, also please watch out for the boxmodel (paddings and margins should be added to an inner-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not post any code, which makes it hard to diagnose, but make sure you have this in you css:

```
html, body{
  width:100%; 
  height:100%:
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
header, header *{
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}
/*your other styles here */
```

Post some code if you want a better answer.

You may not need the width and height at 100% for the body/html, but I'm not 100% sure what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a CSS reset.

Something like:

```
body{margin:0; padding:0;}
```

In your CSS file, should do the trick :)